# How to create an URL in thymeleaf using parameter passed to the template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, templates, thymeleaf

I have created a html template for emails.

Now, i am putting a variable to the context:

```
context.setVariable("invoiceId", invoiceId);
```

In the template I have an  tag:

```
<p><span>To accept the invoice, click <a th:href="http://localhost/accept/${invoiceId}">HERE</a></span></p>
```

but when I am running the app, I get:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "http://localhost/accept/${invoiceId}" (template: "mailTemplate" - line 7, col 47)
```

How can I use the ${invoiceId} variable in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you communicate controllers and views using the model (I am assuming that you use Spring MVC, since you are already using Spring Boot). The only difference here would be

```
 model.addAttribute("invoiceId", invoiceId);
```

Regardless of how you communicate the information, you should be using [url templates](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) when generating urls. Those start with `@`, and generally allow your application to be moved around without having to hard-code its address anywhere:

```
 <a th:href="@{/accept/{id}(id=${invoiceId})}">link text</a>
```

Note how thymeleaf handles those parameters: you use placeholders such as `{foo}` or `{bar}` within your url template, and then explain what they mean at the end, with something like `(foo=${baz},bar=${quux})`, where the contents of the expressions inside the `${}` can be anything that thymeleaf can interpret.

Comment: I solved it partially, but the problem is - I am generating an email template, and when I am using: `<a href="http://localhost/" th:href="@{|accept/${invoiceId}|}">HERE</a>` i get only `accept/5d00d36b2f8c3230d23d388a` as the link, `http://localhost` is nowhere to be found :/

Comment: Follow @tucuxi 's answer. `<a th:href="@{/accept/{id}(id=${invoiceId})}">link text</a>`